# Autoresizing not working in portrait mode

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, ios6

I'm adding a view to `view controller` in which there are certain components. My project needs to support both orientation.

I designed the view controller using **story board** in landscape mode. When a button is pressed in the view controller the view is shown using the scaling animation.

It works perfect when its in landscape mode. When its in landscape mode and button is pressed it works perfect and also the rotation also works perfect. But if its in landscape mode and button is pressed the view doesn't get scaled according to the portrait mode and rotation is also a big problem.

I'm using autosizing and not auto layout

Can anyone please help me? Sorry for my bad english.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: also adjust subviews according orientation using autoresize

Answer (score 0):

Autosizing has never proved to be the best solution for frame changes in orientation modes. Instead, change the frames manually in orientation delegate methods:

**- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;**
**- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;**

check for your current orientation like:

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

```
     if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {

       // change frames here for portrait mode
    }
    else
    {
       // change frames here for landscape mode
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your help
I have solved it by setting a frame. Thanks Evol